# Remove data from array on NSTableView with NSButton with Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nstableview, nstablecellview

I have a NSTableView with data populated from an array.

I've created a button which when tapped should remove the items from that row in the array.

I'm struggling with how you remove the data from the array and delete the table column?

My array reference is:

```
var messagesRef: Firebase!
var messages = [Message]()

func setupFirebase() {

    messagesRef = Firebase(url: "https://url")


    messagesRef.queryLimitedToLast(10).observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let text = snapshot.value["text"] as? String
        let sender = snapshot.value["sender"] as? String
        let imageUrl = snapshot.value["imageUrl"] as? String

        let message = Message(text: text, sender: sender, imageUrl: imageUrl)
        self.messages.append(message)
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    })
}
```

and my table delegate and datasource is:

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return self.messages.count
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let result = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("cell", owner: self) as? secondviewTableCell



    let mess = messages[row]

    result?.textField?.stringValue = mess.text()
    result?.sendertextView.stringValue = mess.sender()

    result?.removeButton.target = self
    result?.removeButton.action = #selector(secondVC.removeFromScreen)



    return result

}

func removeFromScreen(){


    }
```

I've managed to remove the row in the TableView but I'm still struggling with removing the data from the row in the array.

Here's my function to remove the row:

```
@IBAction func removetablerow(object: NSButton) {

    let row = tableView.rowForView( object as NSView )
    if ( row > -1 ) {
        let indexSet = NSIndexSet( index:row )
        tableView.removeRowsAtIndexes( indexSet, withAnimation: NSTableViewAnimationOptions.EffectFade )
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(secondVC.rowDeleted(_:)), userInfo: row, repeats: false )


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy in macOS using a view based table view.

- Create a standard `IBAction` and connect the button in Interface Builder.
- In the action get the row with `row(for view:` and pass the `sender` as `view` parameter, e.g.

  ```
  @IBAction func removeFromScreen(_ sender : NSButton)
  {
      let row = self.tableView.row(for: sender)
      messages.remove(at:row)
      tableView.removeRows(at: IndexSet(integer:row), withAnimation:.effectFade)
      // do other things with the row 
  }
  ```

No extra `target`, no extra `action`.

**Edit:**

The Swift 2 equivalent is:

```
    @IBAction func removeFromScreen(sender : NSButton)
    {
        let row = tableView.rowForView(object)
        messages.removeAtIndex(row)
        tableView.removeRowsAtIndexes( NSIndexSet( index:row ), withAnimation: NSTableViewAnimationOptions.EffectFade )
       // do other things with the row
    }
```

Comment: I get an error back of Value of type 'NSTableView' has no member 'row' with this answer.

Comment: Sorry this is Swift 3 code and apparently you're using Swift 2. You have to remove the item from the `messages` array, too.